# How to convert PDF into image or compress the PDF JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am using next js for my web application, I am having a requirement where when a user uploads a pdf to my input, I will have to compress it (for example: 1MB). I searched here and there, but I am not able to get a prominent solution which can help me out! If I cannot compress a pdf, I would at least like to convert it into an Image, which I can use a library to convert? Can someone help me out on how to compress a PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend:

[Convert API](https://www.convertapi.com/doc/node-library)

You have to pay, but it is a very easy and clean solution.

Alternatively, you can use:

[Shrink PDF](http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/)

...which is a wrapper for ghost script. more complex than the Convert API but easier than implementing ghost script yourself.

Or:

[Ghost script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-scanned-pdf-file/256449#256449)

...You can implement it yourself if you wish.

Realistically, you are not going to be able to get a simple Node package where you can just do `pdf.compress()` and it is done well, unless it is a paid API.

Comment: Is there a reference on how to use them in next js applications? I would like to read and learn them as I dont have much experience with ghostscript!